# optional arguments in the constructor of an object (or method) javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameter-passing

I am studying a jQuery plugin that is called jQuery TE. In the constructor method there is an argument 'options' that is passed :

```
$.fn.jqte = function(options)
```

Normally then when calling this method, we must pass it 'options' argument like this:

```
$(".editor").jqte({
    "css":"example",
    "source":false,
    "titletext":false
});
```

I do not understand that we are not obliged to pass it this argument 'options' like this:

```
$(".editor").jqte();
```

Indeed it does not cause any errors. I do not see anywhere in the source code control something that the argument 'options' is present.

Who can explain this to me, I can not find resources on this problem goes anywhere. Maybe I misread the source code?

Here is the link to the documentation :
http://jqueryte.com/documentation

Thanks !

Comment: I havent checked the source code but its fairly easy to _not do anything_ if the passed object is empty or not passed at all. All you have to do in the constructor is `if(!options) return;` and the function will stop right there if no options are passed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into the source of this plugin, you can find that the options are passed to `jquery.extend()`, which will *Merge the contents of two or more objects together into the first object* ([Source](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)).

You can look at it like this:

```
var default = {left: 0, bottom: 3};
var options = {left: 1, top: 1}

var result = $.extend(default, options); // {left: 1, top: 1, bottom: 3};
```

jQuery extend, in it's turn, allows the second parameter to be passed to be false. If it is false, (or nonexistent, or undefined, or...) then it will just return the first argument ('defaults'). This means that all the options you could possible pass are in the defaults array anyway, meaning if you don't pass options, it will not change the defaults at all.

Comment: Thanks, if I understand correctly, in this case it is because of the method extend () no error is returned. If this method was not in the code then there would be an error. We should therefore have to add something like : `if(!options) return;` . As you say it is because the second argument to extend () false accept that there is no error and you do not have to pass an argument when calling to jqte () . 
So no need to add something like `if(!options) return;`

Comment: @Le Fredd Actually, it is simpler than that. If you don't pass a value to a function that expects one, that value is `undefined`. All you need to do to see if the value was passed or not is check if your value is 'falsy', as `undefined` equates to false. So... `fn(options){ if(!options) return; else alert("Thanks for the options!");}` will not error out if you don't pass it options. `jQuery.extend()` just makes sure it doesn't error out if you do this, as it is very useful to merge defaults with potentially passed options :) But yes, you seem to get the gist of it!

Comment: @Le Fredd could you mark as the answer if it's the answer according to you :)? Cheers